# How to parse efficiently?

Tags: kotlin

Suppose I want to parse the following string: "01:12 Joseph We will have a meeting at 6 PM.". In C I can do (pseudocode):

```
struct data {
    char *time;
    char *name;
    char *message;
};

char *string = "01:12 Joseph We will have a meeting at 6 PM."
struct data notification;
notification.time = strtok(string, " ");
notification.name = strtok(NULL, " ");
notification.message = strtok(NULL, " ");
puts(notification.time); // prints the time it was sent
puts(notification.name); // prints the name of the sender
puts(notification.message); // prints the message content
```

Notice that I am still using the same buffer, which I imagine is the best way to go with kotlin. Now the question is, is it better to leave all data in the same buffer or is it better to create a new object for time, another for name, and another for message?

You should think of this as a constant stream of new notifications being brought up and you have to parse each one in order to position it wherever you want inside a window, which would be useful e.g. for a chat application. So it is whatever that is best for such use case.

Comment: The easiest way to do this is probably `val (time, name, message) = s.split(" ", limit=3)`

Comment: Is the memory usage an actual concern or is this a micro-micro-micro-optimization?

Comment: You should think of this as a constant stream of new notifications being brought up and you have to parse each one in order to position it wherever you want inside a window. So it is whatever that is best for that use case (I will add this to the question).

Comment: Unless you're parsing a million notifications per second containing a thousand characters each on a 10 year old machine, my first comment is probably good enough.

Comment: Post it as an answer, I will accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is probably:

```
val (time, name, message) = s.split(" ", limit=3)
```

https://pl.kotl.in/s7jznsszJ